# Wrong analog readings Intel Edison Arduino Board

Tags: node.js, intel, intel-edison

I´m having problems with the analog readings with the Edison Arduino Board

I had made a program with Node.js and mraa library. the Yocto version is the latest 2.1 and Intel XDK 1912

The circuit is made with one photocell, one analog temp sensor, one moist sensor, and a potentiometer which I don´t move the check the deviation readings. When one of the sensors change their measures the rest readings also change.

If I´m not wrong the readings are 10 bits., from 0-1023, I did´t use setBit() to change the value

Any hint?